# How to divide people into groups?

Tags: kotlin

Divide algorithm:
Part a) **x** people should be divided into groups. Part b) each group size (number of people) should be close as possible to **y**.

What is the most elegant solution to succeed both a and b?

```
package stackoverflow

fun main(args : Array<String>) {

  class Person
  class Group(val people:List<Person>)

  // x=22 and y=6 should produce following groups 6,6,5,5.

  // By using kotlin's Collections.chunked function I can put people into groups.
  val x = 22
  val y = 6
  val people = (1..x).map { Person() }
  val groups = people.chunked(y).map { peopleList -> Group(peopleList) }

  // part a succeed
  assert(groups.size == 4)

  // part b fails
  groups.forEach { print(" "+it.people.size) } // 6 6 6 4
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the c++, assembly and vbscript tags. And the most elegant solution is `people.divideTheWayIWant()`

Comment: I'm trying to get solutions also in other languages than Kotlin.

Comment: [Perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)

Comment: Ari, programming languages are not that different. They might provide different convenience functions, but algorithms remain the same.

Comment: All languages are turing complete so in a way you are right. But It would be nice to see "convenience functions" provided by some assembly language ;)

Comment: Look at your example. It's just fancy assembly, nothing more.

Comment: I'm not sure is it good idea to continue on this but anyways I'm curious what you mean by "fancy assembly"?

Comment: Removed all other language tags, maybe it's better to stick with kotlin if example is written with that.

Comment: Everything boils down to the same thing - to the hardware, that you can't change. Every code you write ends up the same way - machine code. Otherwise it would not be executed. Kotlin tries to make things efficient and easy to write - but eventually they end up in machine code. Sometimes they succeed with their goal, sometimes they don't. Just like everything else. But the main point is: don't use 5 language tags - otherwise you will get -5 points. Ask a concrete programming question, that solves a problem.

Comment: Yeah using different language tags was dump idea. I wanted to see implementations in different languages but if someone want to solve let say javascript related problems and open question with javascript tag he/she most probably is disappointed to see kotlin code as an example.

Comment: "Everything boils down to the same thing - to the hardware, that you can't change. Every code you write ends up the same way - machine code." Code is also written for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of an algorithm where you calculate the number of groups first, then put the first element in the first group, the second element in the second group e.t.c, so the n-th element goes to `n mod groupCount` groups. This way groups are filled as even as possible.

```
val items = (1..22).toList()
val maxGroupSize = 6   
val groups = (items.size + maxGroupSize - 1) / maxGroupSize

// imperative approach
val result = List(groups) { mutableListOf<Int>() }
items.forEachIndexed { index, item -> result[index % groups].add(item) }

println(result)
```

You can do the same in another way with the `groupBy` function:

```
// functional approach
val result = items.withIndex().groupBy({ it.index % groups }, { it.value }).values
println(result)
```

Both ways output the following result:

```
[[1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21], [2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22], [3, 7, 11, 15, 19], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]]
```